# Change if else to switch case statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, switch-statement, break

I have a function with some if…else like this:

```
function updateInputs(data) {
  from = data.from;
  to = data.to;
  rangeInput = $(data.input);
  
  if (rangeInput.hasClass('rangeSalary')) {
    $inputFromSalary.prop("value", from);
    $inputToSalary.prop("value", to);      
  } else if (rangeInput.hasClass('rangeAge')) {
    $inputFromAge.prop("value", from);
    $inputToAge.prop("value", to);
  }
  
  table.draw();
}
```

But I need to add more statements, so I think it is better to use switch…case, so I tried to do this:

```
function updateInputs(data) {
  from = data.from;
  to = data.to;
  rangeInput = $(data.input).hasClass('rangeSalary');

  switch (rangeInput) {
    case 'rangeSalary':
      $inputFromSalary.prop("value", from);
      $inputToSalary.prop("value", to);
      break;
    case 'rangeAge':
      $inputFromAge.prop("value", from);
      $inputToAge.prop("value", to);
      break;
  }

  table.draw();
}
```

But it didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: 1. `.hasClass()` returns a boolean, 2. `rangeInput` will always only tell you if `data.input` has the class `rangeSalary`

Comment: _"But I need to add more statements"_ - Are they always in the same format? The class consists of two parts, the prefix `range` and the "type" of field (`Salary`, `Age`, ...)? And the fields that have to be modified have always the prefixes `$inputFrom` and `$inputTo` + the "type" of the field (`Salary`, `Age`, ...)? Are they always global variables or how did the fields end up in those variables? -> [mcve]

Comment: Yes, they are always in the same format, they are very similar and always have this prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the result you're getting from `hasClass` will be either `true` or `false`, neither of which matches any of your case labels.

If notice that the only thing that's different in the code in the `if`/`else if` blocks (or `case`s) is the jQuery object that you call `prop` on. That being the case, I would lean toward having a map (or object) of those keyed by their name. The name could be from the `name` attribute (if this is a type of element that allows `name` and if it makes sense), or a `data-name` attribute (since you can put a `data-*` attribute on any element). For instance:

```html
<input data-range="Salary" ... >
<input data-name="rangeFromSalary" ... >
<input data-name="rangeToSalary" ... >
<input data-range="Age" ... >
<input data-name="rangeFromAge" ... >
<input data-name="rangeToAge" ... >
```

```js
const rangeInputs = new Map($("[data-name]").map((i, input) => {
    return [input.getAttribute("data-name"), $(input)];
}));
function updateInputs(data) {
    // Note: You need to declare `from` and `to`
    const from = data.from;
    const to = data.to;
    // Get the name for this input
    const rangeName = data.input.getAttribute("data-range");
    // Get the matching jQuery objects
    const rangeFrom = rangeInputs.get(`rangeFrom${inputName}`);
    const rangeTo   = rangeInputs.get(`rangeTo${inputName}`);
    // Got them?
    if (rangeFrom && rangeTo) {
        // Set them
        rangeFrom.prop("value", from);
        rangeTo.prop("value", to);
    }
  
    table.draw();
}
```

---

Note that I added declarations for `from` and `to`. Without them, your code was falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Always declare your variables.

---

In a comment you seemed to worry about using ES2015+ features. Here's the above using only ES5 and below features:

```
var rangeInputs = Object.create(null);
$("[data-name]").each((i, input) => {
    rangeInputs[input.getAttribute("data-name")] = $(input);
});
function updateInputs(data) {
    var from = data.from;
    var to = data.to;
    // Get the name for this input
    var rangeName = data.input.getAttribute("data-range");
    // Get the matching jQuery objects
    var rangeFrom = rangeInputs.get(`rangeFrom${inputName}`);
    var rangeTo   = rangeInputs.get(`rangeTo${inputName}`);
    // Got them?
    if (rangeFrom && rangeTo) {
        // Set them
        rangeFrom.prop("value", from);
        rangeTo.prop("value", to);
    }
  
    table.draw();
}
```

But if you really, really want to use `switch`:

```
function updateInputs(data) {
    var from = data.from;
    var to = data.to;
    var rangeFrom, rangeTo;
    switch (data.input.getAttribute("data-range")) {
        case "rangeSalary":
            rangeFrom = $("rangeFromSalary");
            rangeTo = $("rangeToSalary");
            break;
        case "rangeAge":
            rangeFrom = $("rangeFromAge");
            rangeTo = $("rangeToAge");
            break;
        // ...
    }
    if (rangeFrom && rangeTo) {
        rangeFrom.prop("value", from);
        rangeTo.prop("value", to);
    }
  
    table.draw();
}
```

But notice that now, you have the names in *two* places (the HTML and the code), not just in one place (the HTML). That invites the case where you add or remove them in one place but not the other.

Comment: This is an interesting post, from now I am declaring all my variables! Really appreciate. The problem is it is returning me: `'const' is available in ES6 (use esnext option) or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz).` I would like to use `switch…case` because I am going to add more statement in the future. Please, take a look: http://live.datatables.net/sivelagi/4/edit

Comment: @ArnonRodrigues - Unless you have to support IE11, you can use ES2015+ features just fine these days. But I've added an ES5-and-earlier version above that would work even on IE11. You *could* use `switch` for this, but I think a lookup object/map makes more sense.

Comment: Actually it was live.datatable that warned about the `const` availability. I am analyzing everything you answered, it is very different from I was supposed to do and it seems better. I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much!!